# Can FPGAs be emulated on a CPU?

Tags: fpga

Can FPGAs be emulated on general purpose computers? As per Church-Turing thesis all Turing machines can be emulated on the universal Turing machine. So if the FPGA can emulate processors, can the processors emulate FPGAs?
I am asking this question so I could know if instead of using FPGAs for **Digital** ASIC emulation, can we use a computer instead?
For this question, I am considering only the **digital** applications of FPGAs.

Comment: There are any number of simulators for FPGA that run on PC

Comment: That is essentially what a simulator does. Expect very much less than 1% of real time speeds. Anecdotally, a gate level simulation of the MIPS R-4000 (64-bit RISC) took a month to reach the boot prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be simulated, but not in real time. There's no way that a sequential computer can truly emulate the parallelism going on in most FPGA designs.

Of course, there are exceptions — the FPGA design could *be* a general-purpose computer!

---

In theory, a GPU could be used to make a simulation run faster, but in fact, the kinds of things that GPUs can accelerate are not a good match for general-purpose logic simulation, so as far as I know, no one has put any significant effort into making it work robustly. Instead, advanced simulators take advantage of multiple CPU threads when they are available. Still nowhere near real-time, however.

Comment: Can I use a GPU to emulate FPGA?

Comment: Still off by many orders of magnitude, your not just having to compute the logic, but the clock delays, path delays, gate delays, crosstalk between adjacent routes, edge cases where you have synchronous and asynchronous logic mixed, an FPGA may be a few million logic chunks with many different functions that can be active at the same time. with it being possible to operate them at near the max PLL frequency. a GPU with a few thousand parallel IO is not even close to realtime, more like hours per second in simulation. If it was easy, it would already be the norm.

Comment: The simulation will run faster. If you want a more precise answer, you'll have to be a lot more specific about what you mean by "emulate".

Comment: Sure, Nvidia uses FPGAs (probably -- they don't actually say) to emulate GPUs, but that isn't what you're asking. Also, even those emulators are probably not running at the full design speed.

Answer (score 1):

A sequential computer can emulate a parallel computer. All it needs to do is to compute the "next step" state from the current state without changing the current state in the process of computation. Like, for instance, [Conways Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is clearly a parallel machine, but can be easily simulated, and many times has been done. The array of the "next generation" cells must be computed without touching the "current generation" array.

Also, even in the Game of Life's theoretically contains the infinitely large board, a cell colony under investigation normally only contains limited number of cells. The amount of time and memory to track generations of any initially finite colony till any time into the future may be large but will not be infinite.

Hence there are no any "fundamental" reasons why FPGA cannot be emulated on the logical level. A logical level emulator (kind of "Verilog interpreter") is not difficult at all to implement and many exist. They are usually not intended as "FPGA replacements", being just tools for quick pre-testing.

An emulator that takes various (often unexpected and undesired) physical effects into consideration (like signal propagation delays, for instance) is much more complex to implement and needs lots of information about how the final "synthesis" of the circuitry has been done - Verilog alone is not enough. While working with Xilinx software I have observed that the emulator tries to move towards these capabilities, even it it stays limited. Again, the emulator was the testing tool and not FPGA replacement.

The question if FPGA emulator can replace FPGA in production is very difficult answer, depends on the task. CPU is ASIC, this gives some advantage. Another question is, how fast is "fast enough" and how ancient is the FPGA being replaced.

Comment: Conway's Game of Life can only be simulated on a computer with unlimited memory and no time constraints. Since this automaton can continue indefinitely, it can't be truly simulated or be built. It exists in theoretical computer science. Your answer is correct from a theoretical computer science point of view. But it might be beneficial to other readers if you could elaborate a little on the physical limitations.